# Why is the App Detail Page rejecting my all images?

Tags: facebook

I have all of the images in the correct format and size for my App Detail page, but Facebook rejects everyone with a generic "*The image you are trying to upload are invalid. It may be corrupt, of wrong file format or the wrong size*" error.

Here is the app referenced if needed: http://a.pgtb.me/3CTv6v. Although not sure why it would be.

I haven't found anyone else having these problems. What is the big issue? I'm using the latest version of Firefox for Mac.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the file has the correct extension (png, jpg, gif) and make sure it is in the correct format. If you are still having problems, open the image in your favourite editor, and click "Save As", and resave it as a valid jpg, png or gif format.